# Regular expression in Python issue

Tags: python, regex

I have the below code in one of my configuration files:
appPackage_name = sqlncli
appPackage_version = 11.3.6538.0

The left side is the key and the right side is value.

Now i want to be able to replace the value part with something else given a key in Python.

```
import re
Filepath = r"C:\Users\bhatsubh\Desktop\Everything\Codes\Python\OO_CONF.conf"
key = "appPackage_name"
value = "Subhayan"
searchstr = re.escape(key) + " = [\da-zA-Z]+"
replacestr = re.escape(key) + " = " + re.escape(value)
filedata = ""
with open(Filepath,'r') as File:
    filedata = File.read()
File.close()
print ("Before change:",filedata)
re.sub(searchstr,replacestr,filedata)
print ("After change:",filedata)
```

I assume there is something wrong with the regex i am using. But i am not able to figure out what . Can someone please help me ?

Comment: Can you modify your code so it can be run by someone who doesn't have a copy of `OO_CONF.conf`? Letting others test your code (and thus, test their answers) is part of the criteria given at http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve (requiring that code in a question be **M**inimal -- having only the smallest amount of code, smallest set of dependencies, &c. needed to reproduce -- while also being **C**omplete and **V**erifiable).

Comment: You should not use `re.escape` with the replacement pattern. Also, the version contains dots, and `[\da-zA-Z]` does not, add it there.

Comment: It would also be helpful to include your "before" and "after" output printed, as well as the output you expect. Right now, you're giving us your code, and saying it has "an issue", but not in any way describing what that issue is or what the code *should* do.

Comment: Use it so: `searchstr = r"({} *= *)[\da-zA-Z.]+".format(re.escape(key))` and then `replacestr = r"\1{}".format(value)` and then `filedata = re.sub(searchstr,replacestr,filedata)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the following fix:

```
import re
#Filepath = r"C:\Users\bhatsubh\Desktop\Everything\Codes\Python\OO_CONF.conf"
key = "appPackage_name"
value = "Subhayan"
#searchstr = re.escape(key) + " = [\da-zA-Z]+"
#replacestr = re.escape(key) + " = " + re.escape(value)
searchstr = r"({} *= *)[\da-zA-Z.]+".format(re.escape(key))
replacestr = r"\1{}".format(value)
filedata = "appPackage_name = sqlncli"
#with open(Filepath,'r') as File:
#    filedata = File.read()
#File.close()
print ("Before change:",filedata)
filedata = re.sub(searchstr,replacestr,filedata)
print ("After change:",filedata)
```

See the [Python demo](http://ideone.com/ES93O3)

There are several issues: you should not escape the replacement pattern, only the literal user-defined values in the *regex pattern*. You can use a capturing group (a pair of unescaped `(...)`) and a backreference (here, `\1` since the group is only one in the pattern) to restore the part of the matched string you need to keep rather than build that replacement string dynamically. As the version value contains dots, you should add a `.` to the character class, `[\da-zA-Z.]`. You also need to assign new value after replacing, so as to actually modify it.